# Android Number Format Exception using EditText

Tags: android, if-statement, floating-point, android-edittext, numberformatexception

I have a simple process running

Put simply the user inputs a number into an EditText, picks Radio Button and then presses calculate. The radio buttons are connected to if statements that in turn direct towards floats that are returned replacing the number shown in the EditText.  However it appears that if the calculate button is pressed before any numbers are entered then a number format exception occours causing the app to crash.

For now I will enter a default value into the EditText to decrease the chances of this happening, but i was wondering if there was a way to avoid an exception all together using something like an if statement or something similar

here is some example code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;

import com.admob.android.ads.AdManager;
import com.admob.android.ads.AdView;
import com.medialets.android.analytics.MMAnalyticsManager;

public class Area extends Activity {
    private EditText text9;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.area);
            text9 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText09);

    public void myClickHandler09(View view){
switch (view.getId()) {
case R.id.Button09:
    RadioButton SeveralRadioButtons = (RadioButton) findViewById (R.id.RadioButton901);
    float inputValue = Float.parseFloat(text9.getText().toString());
    String checkValue = String.valueOf(inputValue);

    if (checkValue.equals("")){
        text9.setText(String.valueOf(""));
   } else {

     if (SeveralRadioButtons.isChecked())  {
            text9.setText(String
                    .valueOf(conversionfactor(inputValue)));
   }
       break;
}}}

private double conversionfactor(float f){
        return f * 6.4516;
    }
```

Where 
     (SeveralRadioButtons)
is called there are in fact several radio buttons and an if statement and private double for each one respectively

As you can see I have already made an attempt at fixing the problem but the number format exception still appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as following the other suggestions for checking for `null` and `""` values, you can also catch the `NumberFormatException` and handle the error case.  You could abort the calculation and perhaps show an error message.

Handling the exception if it is thrown means that if there is some other edge case that you have missed, your users won't experience a full application crash.

Answer (score 0):

put an if statement around your conversion checking for null (first!) or an empty string. A default value works until people put an empty string in the text box.

Comment: Heya, turns out my EditText is in fact a float so I just created a string with the same value "String checkValue = String.valueOf(inputValue);"      I then added an if statement like you said "if (checkValue.equals(null)){
   text9.setText(String.valueOf(null));
    } else {"    The else statement just contains the rest of the conversions, so the function should check for a null value first but alas there is still an exception. Is there anything you can see here that should be staring me in the face =(

Comment: you can't say valueOf(null). that is handing it a NullReferenceException. You must set the text to an empty string if you are going to do it that way. it would help if you put some code in the question too.

Answer (score 0):

In the onClickListener of your button you can write an if statement that checks if the string is null or "" before actually sending the number to wherever you are sending it...